# Example for Java Trace and its usages?

Tags: java, trace

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/trace.html

Could anyone please provide me couple of examples of how to use Java trace and explain me it usages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPDA is for remote debugging of any java application..

Generally it is used to debug application which is deployed at remote location, major stack is web applications..

you can get excellent how to at here

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/debugging-your-tomcat-webapp-with-eclipse/

Comment: Could you please point me to some good link about Jpda/trace?

Comment: i started with the link provided above, it explaines every required think about jpda..